# Write the given set as an interval or as a union of two intervals

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Write the given set as an interval or as a union of two intervals.
$$\left\{x:|10x-9|<\frac{1}{11}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

So you have $$-{1\over 11}<10x-9<{1\over 11}\;\;\;/+9$$

now $$-{98\over 11}<10x <{100\over 11}\;\;\;/:10$$

so $$-{98\over 110}<x <{10\over 11}$$

and this is just one iterval $$\Big(-{98\over 110},{10\over 11}\Big)$$

Comment: Nice and concise.

Comment: Thanks @drhab...